# WPF combobox-like custom control

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls, popup

I would like to create custom control that will look like standard WPF `ComboBox`, but instead of instead of having an `ItemsPresenter` in the popup there will be another custom control. So, I created a new class that derives from `System.Windows.Controls.Control`, added a `IsDropDownOpen` property and created a style that is actually a copy of default `ComboBox` style (main idea is that the `Popup.IsOpen` and `ToggleButton.IsPressed` properties are bound to the `IsDropDownOpen` property of the control).

The problem is that the `Popup` is not closed when I click outside of the control.

I took a look at the `ComboBox` class in the Reflector and found out that `ComboBox` used some logic to update the `IsDropDownOpen` property when it loses mouse capture. But that code uses some internal classes. Is there any alternative way to determine if the user clicked outside of the control and close the `Popup`?

UPD: I didn't find the way to attach a file to post, so I uploaded sample project [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?btfav7vfk36qly0)

There is a custom control that looks like ComboBox, but it has a TreeView in a popup. When you open popup and click outside of the control it closes automatically, but if you open popup, expand 'Item2' and then click outside the popup isn't closed. The question is how to fix this?

Comment: @RQDQ: What exactly do you need? Control template? As I said It's the same as default combobox template, but instead of ItemsPresenter there is an other control.

Comment: The idea is we want to see what you already have so we don't have to reinvent the wheel just to help you.

Comment: @RQDQ - I updated my original post with the link to the sample project and additional question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solves the problem.

In the static contructor:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(CustomComboBox), Mouse.LostMouseCaptureEvent, new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseCaptureLost));
```

Event handler implementation:

```
private void OnMouseCaptureLost(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (Mouse.Captured != _container)
   {
      if (e.OriginalSource != _container)
      {
         Mouse.Capture(_container, CaptureMode.SubTree);
         e.Handled = true; 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what `_container` means and what were all the steps from required to get it to work?

Comment: The linked file no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `Control.LostFocus` event, maybe handling that would be sufficient for this.

Comment: this event isn't fired when popup is shown and you click outside of it.